# How do I structure the dependencies in a Gradle MultiModule Project?

Tags: java, spring, gradle, build.gradle, multi-module

So I am currently working on a multimodular spring boot application and I am using gradle as the built tool.
So I have a main module which consists of the following:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
}

group = 'ez.ndvz'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

And in the settings.gradle I have included my submodules.
And now this is how my submodule build.gradle looks like:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:3.0.2'
    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.26'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Right now as it is it works all fine but my question is since domain is the submodule shouldn't it inherit the parents dependencies and plugins?
Everytime I try and remove the plugins the domain module won't work
Shouldn't they be inherited from the parents module

Comment: No, not if you don't configure the submodules in the parent module.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by configure the submodules in the parent module
I have added the submodules in the settings.gradle

Comment: Using the `allprojects` and `subprojects` in the main project to specify shared resources/dependencies. What you hvae now are the dependencies that apply to the project itself only.